# MariaDB: Can't linked Database tables to each other

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a problem that I don't know how to fix, I'm working on an IMDB like system, which I've scraped out some movies and their actors in seperate tables:

MOVIES TABLE:

| movie_id(PK) | name | revenue | release_date | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Avengers | 19,238,834 | 2010/2/20 | 8.8 |

PERSON TABLE:

| person_id(PK) | name | DOB | nationality | bio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | Robert Downey Jr. | 1965/4/4 | US | Robert D. Jr. is an American actor. |

## =======

**Now the problem is that I have another bridge table for MOVIE-PERSON:**

| movie_name | person_name | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Avengers | Robert Downey, Jr. | actor |

I need in my third bridge table to replace each movie with its corresponding movie_id and same goes to person --> person_id.

So it would look like this:

UPDATED bridge table:

| movie_id | person_id | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | actor |

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And where did you get stuck?

Comment: So I have the bridge table right now filled with movie names and actor names, I want to change each name to its corresponding id, as a foreign key, as I will be adding ID(primary key field) in the two main tables (movies table, person table). *I’ve fixed my main post with what I said to make more sense

Comment: What's your exact question about this? Please edit your question to contain all relevant information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If movies names are unique then I guess you need something like this

```
-- Creating your first table
CREATE TABLE MOVIES(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50));
-- Inserting sample data to your first table
INSERT INTO MOVIES(id, name) values(1, 'Avengers');
                                             
-- Creating your many-to-many table, Add foreign key to the first table
CREATE TABLE MOVIEPERSON(movie_name VARCHAR(50), movie_id INTEGER);

-- Inserting sample data to your many-to-many table
INSERT INTO MOVIEPERSON(movie_name) values('Avengers');

-- Fill data in the many-to-many table id column based in data from first table
UPDATE MOVIEPERSON, MOVIES  
SET MOVIEPERSON.movie_id=MOVIES.id
WHERE MOVIEPERSON.movie_name = MOVIES.name
```

Another way you can achieve that using join, and for both first and second tables

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIES(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO MOVIES(id, name) values(1, 'Avengers');

CREATE TABLE PERSONS(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO PERSONS(id, name) values(5, 'Tom Something');


CREATE TABLE MOVIEPERSON(movie_name VARCHAR(50), person_name VARCHAR(50), movie_id INTEGER, person_id INTEGER);


INSERT INTO MOVIEPERSON(movie_name, person_name) values('Avengers', 'Tom Something');

UPDATE 
     MOVIEPERSON mp
INNER JOIN MOVIES m ON mp.movie_name = m.name
INNER JOIN PERSONS p ON mp.person_name = p.name
SET mp.movie_id=m.id, mp.person_id=p.id;
```